# Where to put python module i need for several projects?

Tags: python, module, project, directory-structure

Let's say I have a python module called *custom_colors.py* in which I create some variables I am using in multiple projects in different working directories. So I am wondering what's the best practice of how to work with such helper files?

copy them into each project's folder?

So far I thought about creating a folder for all helper files like this and import whenever needed

```
import os
# change workding directory to helper files folder and load own modules
os.chdir(helper_files_path)
import utils.custom_colors as cc
```

but for this approach I always need to change the working directory first.

How do you guys handle such stuff?

Comment: You can append the path to "sys.path" instead.

Comment: Multiples approaches: 1. Copy them in each project. 2. Turn it into a custom Python package. 3. Add it to `PYTHONPATH`

Answer (score 2):

You keep them in a central location, but you don't make your script responsible for finding that location. Instead, you tell the *interpreter* where it is by using `PYTHONPATH`.

```
import os
import utils.customer_colors as cc

...
```

If the path to your module is something like `/path/to/lib/utils.py`, then run Python with

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/lib python myscript.py
```

You can add this change to your environment so that you Python will always look in `/path/to/lib` when searching for a module.

Taking this one step further, package your library so that you can install it using `python setup.py install` or `pip install mylib`, then create a virtual environment for each project and install `mylib` in the virtual environment.